# read image file using path

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Is it possible to read image file in `javascript` or `typescript` from local disc using absolute path.

I read that for security reason, the browsers does not allow access to absolute path & file systems.

Is this true?. Or is there any way to access local files ?

Comment: If you just want to read, it's possible. But writing/editing file is not possible as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey you can save page from page option on browser and can attach image using absolute path**

save website page in local by clicking save as on right click option on browser and can set any local image using absolute or relative path

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to *read* the contents of the file, you can get away with asking the user for input. Something like:

```js
document.getElementById("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", function() {
  alert(this.files[0].name)
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileUpload"/>
```

Comment: Did you think that create assets with files in project and using them in < img src="./...." is a good solution ?

Comment: @WalterWhite Oh, so are these files assets that ship with your project? Are they hosted in the same server?

Comment: The file are hosted in local machine, data come from scaner and guid = filename is sending from a server as  json.

Comment: @WalterWhite Yeah, if you have a user interacting with the server, you can only access the files that the user gives you. So I think `<input type="file"/>` is your best bet. Another option would be to have a client application running in the user's machine and send files to your server through it, but I might be more than you need.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read files in the browser from a path. To read the content of a file, you need a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object, which is generated by `<input type="file">` inputs, or through drag-and-drop.

In other words, you need the user to give you the file to read - you cannot simply read arbitrary files from the harddisk (for good reason - we don't want websites to simply be able to read all of our files).

Comment: @Brijolaxew this is good to create assets in project and store them and assets directory and later using in <img src="  " ..>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to read a locale file `test.csv` with javascript:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Check for the various File API support.
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                console.log("File APIs are supported !");
            } else {
                console.log('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
            }
            //Create a test.csv in the same path as this .html
            $.get('test.csv', function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Note: Place a `test.csv` in same directory of the .html and then test Firefox. In google chrome you will get crossOrigin error if you are not hosting both .html and test.csv in server.

Comment: It's loading correctly, the error you are seeing because on server there is no `test.csv`
Just copy paste the html code in `index.html` and write a dummy `test.csv` in the same path. and open in browser

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried this?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader

From the link:

> The FileReader object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer, using File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read.

Comment: Yes i try this and this is good option when we don't use the path. Returned files also don't contains path to file.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to obtain an absolute path from javascript. If this was possible, a web page could read your whole filesystem without installing anything on your computer.